# Tabbar button inset wrong after update Xcode 11 and IOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

after update to Xcode 11, my tabbar inset look wrong, how to fix this?

Example

[image]

Comment: Please Share your code as well.

Comment: i just use storyboard

Comment: Have you make sure about the safe area?

Comment: yes . before update to xcode 11 , its good

Answer (score 2):

Did you check titles for each tab? a single space was the issue for me at the time i had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the tab bar items titles to nil solved the problem.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        clearTitles()
    }

    func clearTitles() {
        guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
        for (index, _) in items.enumerated(){
            tabBar.items![index].title = nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

My temporary solution:

```
class CustomTabbarController: UITabBarController {
     override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.tabBar.items?[0].imageInsets = .zero
            self.tabBar.items?[1].imageInsets = .zero
            self.tabBar.items?[2].imageInsets = .zero
        }
    }
}
```